# Question about the use of "at outset"

Tags: word-usage, articles, usage, definite-article

Is "at outset" grammatically correct to use as in the following

> These dormitories were at outset for senior girls

or is "at the outset" better?

Comment: It doesn't look right, but it's hard to tell because we don't know exactly what you're trying to say.  Can you rephrase it in a different way?

Comment: "At *the* outset" is correct in itself, but seems an odd choice in that particular sentence. "These dormitories were initially intended for senior girls" sounds a lot better to me.

Answer (score 1):

"At the outset" is more modern, so if you want to sound like you are using contemporary English, then "at the outset" would indeed be "better."

**outset** *noun*

> 3. a. The action or fact of setting out upon a journey, course of action, business, etc.; a start, a beginning. Now chiefly in **at the outset**, **from the outset**.

(*Oxford English Dictionary* [emphases *OED's*])

There seem to be certain contexts in which *at outset* is a fixed phrase, such as in

A

> *En garde*
>       French for "on guard"; spoken **at outset** to warn the participants to take a defensive position. (Wikipedia: [Glossary of Fencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_fencing))

B
in scientific papers, such as [this one](https://books.google.com/books?id=4rgjBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=%22at+outset%22+define&source=bl&ots=3XtP3G0vPf&sig=DluUJekLtcliiJu3Gsr9AeMam0A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiErOb5-7TNAhWIOiYKHQBBC1kQ6AEITjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22at%20outset%22%20define&f=false)

> The formerly proposed percentage of patients that achieve normal weight (or overweight) is clearly unjust to to patients with more severe obesity **at outset**

I would recommend using *at the outset* or *from the outset* rather than *at outset* unless you have a special reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

[**at the outset**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+the+outset) is the only grammatically correct way to say it. You can also say **from the outset**. The only time you would ever see **at outset** used like that would probably be only as part of a news article headline.

[Example](http://www.capebretonpost.com/News/Local/2016-03-07/article-4458987/Charges-dismissed-at-outset-of-hearing/1):

> Charges dismissed at outset of hearing

Answer (score 0):

I agree that 'outset' needs the article 'the.'  However, I would suggest that you might consider 'initially' to replace 'at (the) outset.'

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.